# Help on Installing Ubuntu on a Late 2008 MacBook with No Operating System and a Broken Disk Drive?

Tags: live-usb, mac, macbook

I have a MacBook 4,1 (Late 2008) that I accidently formatted and now has no OS; whenever I boot after a period of time I get a flashing folder icon with a question mark. The Mac also has a broken disk drive, whenever I put a disk in it takes it in makes funny noises and spits it back out again. I do have a Snow Leopard OS X Install USB but I am not able to install it as it was originally disgned for a Mac, but I still am able to access the tools on it such as terminal, disk utility etc. I understand that the process might be lengthy, but I am not afraid, computers have always been a hobby for me :). Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you so much, I am so happy to see people take their own time to help others ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider partitioning the drive from the install usb, and making it a dual boot system with one partition for OS X and another for ubuntu. You can use disk editor to create a partition (Mac OS X Extended Journaled) and install OS X onto there.

You can then boot from a live usb created on another computer (use rEFInd if you cant boot using the option key) and format and install onto the other partition (ext4).

Hopefully this vague answer will set you on the right track. Your welcome in advance!